# avoid displayed figures during sweave/pgfsweave compilation

Tags: r, sweave

When compiling with sweave/pgfsweave, every time a figure is created in R it is shown in a graphics windows (during the sweave compilation process). This is helpful in many cases as I can see what the figures look like as the document is being compiled.

But when I compile through ssh a large document this can be very slow. Is there a way to tell sweave/pgfsweave to avoid displaying the figure during the compilation (I still want the figure in the final pdf document though).

Answer (score 4):

For interactive sessions, the `figs.only` Sweave option controls this behavior. To plot figures only to the target graphics files (and **not** to a console graphical window) set `figs.only=TRUE`.

As explained in the `RweaveLatex` help file:

> figs.only: logical (‘FALSE’).  By default each figure chunk is run
>             once, then re-run for each selected type of graphics.  That
>             will open a default graphics device for the first figure
>             chunk and use that device for the first evaluation of all
>             subsequent chunks.  If this option is true, the figure chunk
>             is run only for each selected type of graphics, for which a
>             new graphics device is opened and then closed.

As with other Sweave options, you can set this option: (1) for the current compilation (e.g. `Sweave("example.Rnw", figs.only=TRUE)`; (2) within the `.Rnw` file, using `\SweaveOpts{figs.only=TRUE}`; or (3) as a global default, by putting `SWEAVE_OPTIONS="figs.only=TRUE"` in, e.g., `$R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site`

Comment: I recommend (2) because it is self-contained (so always reproducible); (1) is bad and (3) is worse.

Comment: @Yihui -- Thanks for adding that. Also (though it's slightly off-topic) many thanks for your work on the formatR package.

Answer (score 2):

`figs.only` is the correct way to go, and I also want to mention the default graphical device in R here:

For now you may look at this: http://yihui.name/en/2010/12/a-special-graphics-device-in-r-the-null-device/

After R 2.14.1 (not released yet) you will be able to set the default device to a null PDF device, which is both safe and fast: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/9

Answer (score 1):

If you sweave from the command line instead of in an interactive session, graphics aren't produced in an interactive graphic window.

You can run R from the command line by just typing `R CMD Sweave mydoc.Rnw` or via a batch file, or a makefile for larger projects.  I've started to use makefiles for many of my sweave documents as it handles dependencies, can clear up after itself and much more.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be

```
<<label=myplotlabel, fig=TRUE, include=FALSE>>=
graph code
@
```

then

```
\begin{figure}[h]
   \includegraphics[width=6cm, height=6cm]{myplotlabel}
   \caption{My Plot}
   \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
```