# Set default arguments to Sweave code chunk

Tags: r, latex, sweave, noweb

I am using [cacheSweave](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cacheSweave/index.html) with a large LaTeX Sweave document. Rather than put

```
<<cache=true>>=
...snip...
@
```

in almost all of my code chunks, I would rather have `cache=true` be the default, and use

```
<<cache=false>>=
...snip...
@
```

when I don't want a code chunk to be cached. How can I set this default argument for code chunks?

I am currently using the following code to compile the Sweave document:

```
library(cacheSweave)
Sweave(infile, driver = cacheSweaveDriver)
```

Comment: for consistency with R, I recommend you to write TRUE/FALSE instead of true/false; as a side note, you can use either `opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)` or `\SweaveOpts{cache=TRUE}` in the knitr package (http://yihui.name/knitr), which also supports cache.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, but using `\SweaveOpts{}` to set the option somewhere early in your `*.Snw` file (e.g. in the document preamble) is probably the handiest:

```
\SweaveOpts{cache=TRUE}
```

As described in the Sweave manual, a `\SweaveOpts{}` statement anywhere in a documentation chunk will modify the defaults for "*all code chunks after the statement*".

A couple of other options are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276069/avoid-displayed-figures-during-sweave-pgfsweave-compilation/8276990#8276990).